# Obtener horas en un select anidado y sumar valores con ajax y php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Buen día comunidad recurro a esta fuente de conocimiento, ya que soy nuevo en ajax,js.
El problema que tengo , tengo dos select anidados uno  de funciones y otro de cursos,
hace todo la funcion bien, es decir escojo "informatica" muestra cursos de informatica y en un input las horas que dura.
Lo que necesito es el valor del input vale "10" sumarlo con mi segundo curso y dar un total de 40 horas ,habilitar botón si cumple con las horas requeridas.
No se como sacar ese valor para hacer la suma.
adjunto mi codigo
index.php

```
<select class="form-control" placeholder="selecciona" name="estado1" id="estado1" required>
                            <option></option>
                            <?php
                            $query = "SELECT id_funcion,funcion FROM funcion_especifica  ORDER BY funcion";
                            if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($query)) {
                                while ($row3 = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                            ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row3['id_funcion']; ?> ">
                                        <?php echo $row3['funcion']; ?>
                                    </option>
                            <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td align=" center" class="col-md-2">
                        <select class="form-control" placeholder="selecciona" name="municipio1" id="municipio1" required>
                            <option></option>

                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <center>
                            <label name="localidad1" id="localidad1">

                            </label>

                        </center>
```

> ajax

```
                     //valores ajax
                     $(document).ready(function() {
                     $('#estado').on('change', function() {
                     var funcion = $(this).val();
                     // console.log(funcion);
                     if (funcion) {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'select_prueba_get.php',
                        data: 'id_funcion=' + funcion,

                        success: function(html) {
                            //console.log(html + 'data');
                            $('#municipio').html(html);



                        }
                    });
                }

            });
            $('#municipio').on('change', function() {
                var stateID = $(this).val();
                //console.log(stateID);
                if (stateID) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'select_prueba_get.php',
                        data: 'id_curso=' + stateID,

                        success: function(html) {
                            // console.log(html);
                            $('#localidad').html(html);


                        }
                    });
                }

            });
```

> select_prueba_get.php

```
    //select_prueba_get.php

<?php
require 'conexiondnc.php';
if (isset($_POST["id_funcion"])) {

$continente = $_POST['id_funcion'];
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_curso,curso FROM cursos2023 WHERE 
id_funcion=$continente order by curso");
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['id_curso'] . "'>" . $row['curso'] . "</option>";
}
}
if (isset($_POST["id_curso"])) {
$continente = $_POST['id_curso'];
$sql = ("SELECT horas FROM cursos2023 WHERE id_curso=$continente order by curso");

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$cadena = $row['horas'];
//echo $cadena = $row['horas'];
echo '<input id="suma" name="num1" value=' . $cadena . ' disabled/>';
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrJLt.png): **Necesito sacar el valor de las horas  para sumar y mostrarlo en un input**

Comment: Hola, cuesta mucho interpretar el codigo asi que prefieron que me respondas:  dode se debe realizar la suma en el fronend (javascript) o en el backend (php); que has intentado para lograr esa suma ...

Comment: La respuesta que me compartes es  correcta, si yo hago un  console.log(html); de municipio me trae el 20, suponiendo que  guarda ese valor en  $('#localidad').html(html); ,  y lo imprime en el id="localidades".  Yo al querer obtener ese valor para la suma, no trae ningun valor. No se como pasar el valor al id="localidad" que me trae como respuesta del archivo select_prueba_get.php  o de que otra forma lo puedo resolver.
Los select dependiente uno del otro.

Comment: tu sabes que hace .html()???

Answer (score 0):

No me voy a romper la cabeza ajajaja, y viendo que tiene algo de javascript lo vamos a resolver con javascript:

```js
        // Función para calcular la suma o resta y actualizar el input
        function actualizarResultado() {
            // Obtener los valores de los selects
            const valorSelect1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('select1').value);
            const valorSelect2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('select2').value);
            const valorSelect3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('select3').value);
            const valorSelect4 = parseInt(document.getElementById('select4').value);

            // Calcular la suma de los valores
            const total = valorSelect1 + valorSelect2 + valorSelect3 + valorSelect4;

            // Actualizar el valor del input con el resultado
            document.getElementById('result').value = total;
        }

        // Agregar eventos de cambio a cada select
        document.querySelectorAll('.number-select').forEach(select => {
            select.addEventListener('change', actualizarResultado);
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculadora de Suma/Resta</title>
</head>
<body>

    <label for="select1">Select 1:</label>
    <select id="select1" class="number-select">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

    <label for="select2">Select 2:</label>
    <select id="select2" class="number-select">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

    <label for="select3">Select 3:</label>
    <select id="select3" class="number-select">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

    <label for="select4">Select 4:</label>
    <select id="select4" class="number-select">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

    <label for="result">Resultado:</label>
    <input type="text" id="result" readonly>


</body>
</html>
```

Explicacion... esto es sencillo y quiero que cada script que hagas lo veas de la siguiente forma:

- Eventos: quieres capturar cuando se cambia el valor del select, tienes que hacerlo entonces con javascript.
- Quiere sumar valores: tienes que crear un mecanimos para identificar los inputs/selects para obtener sus valores.
- por ultimo actualizar un campo asignandole un valor especifico.

**Lo que falta:** toma mi codigo y adaptalo a tu necesidad, es lo que haras cuando sean Tareas: busca, investigar, adaptar, mejorar y debuguear.